How to connect to three Kafka brokers from outside Docker?
I want to create Kafka with three brokers in Docker and use them in C# application from outside Docker.
I have this in my docker-compose:
  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka1
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094,CONTROLLER://:9093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka1:9092,OUTSIDE://host.docker.internal:9094
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE   
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: broker,controller
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: 1@kafka1:9093,2@kafka2:9093,3@kafka3:9093
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 2
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: /var/lib/kafka/data
      KAFKA_SOCKET_REQUEST_MAX_BYTES: 209715200
      CLUSTER_ID: "1"
    ports:
      - 65000:9092 # Mapping for INSIDE
      - 65001:9093 # Mapping for CONTROLLER
      - 65006:9094 # Mapping for OUTSIDE
    networks:
      - mynetwork

And similar one for kafka2 and kafka3.
My C# .NET application code as:
await _kafkaService.InitializeKafkaTopics(); // it creates my-topic

var config = new ConsumerConfig
{
   GroupId = "my-group-id",
   BootstrapServers = "host.docker.internal:65006,host.docker.internal:65007,host.docker.internal:65008",
   AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest,
   PartitionAssignmentStrategy = PartitionAssignmentStrategy.RoundRobin
};

using var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(config).Build();
consumer.Subscribe("my-topic");

var task = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var consumeResult = consumer.Consume();
            await processMessageAsync(consumer, consumeResult);
        }
    }
    catch (ConsumeException e)
    {
        _logger.LogError("Error in consumer");
        processErrorHandler(e.Error);
    }
});

But I keep on receiving:

%3|1726579828.152|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka3:9092/bootstrap]: kafka3:9092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'kafka3:9092': Unknown host.  (after 2322ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1726579828.153|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: rdkafka#producer-1: kafka3:9092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'kafka3:9092': Unknown host.  (after 2322ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1726579828.868|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka2:9092/bootstrap]: kafka2:9092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'kafka2:9092': Unknown host.  (after 2336ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1726579828.869|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: rdkafka#producer-1: kafka2:9092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'kafka2:9092': Unknown host.  (after 2336ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1726579829.164|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka1:9092/bootstrap]: kafka1:9092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'kafka1:9092': Unknown host.  (after 2325ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1726579829.164|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka1:9092/bootstrap]: 3/3 brokers are down

Which means that it's trying to access it from outside of Docker as if it was inside Docker.
I have read similar threads on StackOverflow but they don't deal with three Kafka brokers at the same time and some of them even suggest not using ports in docker-compose. I don't see how it can work if I don't use ports because I need to use these externally. Those other posts also deal with Zookeeper which I don't use.
What am I doing wrong? How can I make sure that I can read from these three Kafka topics from my C# .NET application outside Docker?
Thank you!

Zookeeper isn't the problem and one broker works the same as 3 (though there's no reason to run 3 on the same machine). You cannot remap host ports with kafka containers. Each must match your advertised listeners. That's it. Your c# code should also be in the same compose file / network, not need to use host.docker.internal

@OneCricketeer Thanks! The thing is that I would prefer to keep C# code outside of Docker. I have changed my configuration to map ports as 9092:9092, 9093:9093, 9094:9094 and configuration of C# app to localhost:9094. I have also changed host.docker.internal to kafka1 in docker-compose and removed kafka 2 and 3. But now I keep on receiving "JoinGroup failed: Broker: Inconsistent group protocol". Could you, please, advice?

Please [edit] your question to show your latest changes, or refer to the duplicate post. You need to set localhost in the advertised listeners and use that in your code. OUTSIDE://kafka1:9094 would be expected to return a DNS exception since that name isn't known outside of Docker
